# How would you arrange wormholes throughout the galaxy so that they don't violate the Chronology protection conjecture?

Tags: physics, hard-science, space-travel, relativity, wormholes

Any form of FTL, including traversable wormholes, allows backwards time travel. (EDIT: I mean going backwards in coordinate time. We get to closed timelike curves later in the post.) My world has traversable wormholes, so I just bite the bullet and say *yes*, anyone with the ability to use wormholes can travel back in time as much as they like. For example, if you want to appear on the moon 1 second ago, you can set up wormholes to do that.

How do we deal with time travel paradoxes then? Well, there is one rule about how the wormholes work. You *can't* arrange them into closed timelike curves. The moon example is fine, because even though you can go to the moon 1 second ago, it takes you at least 1.28 seconds to get back to Earth, so you can't actually change your own past using them. In fact, most things we think of as time travel just don't work; time travel is only allowed because physics demand it, but we take away its ability for you to influence your own past.

What if you tried to make a wormhole that took you to the moon *2 seconds* in the past? Well, if you tried to set up the wormholes to do that, the wormholes would just blow up. Quite violently in fact. All the wormholes are forced to obey the [Chronology protection conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture) in my world. If you try to arrange wormholes close to violating it, enough wormholes will blow up that the violation is never reached (usually more). Quoting from that Wikipedia article:

> Initial attempts to apply semiclassical gravity to the traversable wormhole time machine indicated that at exactly the moment that wormhole would first allow for closed timelike curves, quantum vacuum fluctuations build up and drive the energy density to infinity in the region of the wormholes.

Anyways, with those rules, humanity wants to take over the galaxy with these things, but without the wormholes blowing up. What is the most efficient solution to colonizing the galaxy with wormholes that obey Chronology protection?

- There are currently wormholes that can take you from Earth to Alpha Centauri, 4.2 light years in the future. The goal is to build wormholes from Alpha Centauri to every other solar system in the galaxy (the government does not want people building all of these wormholes from Earth for alleged safety reasons).
- Around Alpha Centauri, there is a machine that creates wormholes. At creation time, the mouths are created at almost the same point in spacetime, but after that can be separated and carried wherever. EDIT: The machine specifically can create [Ellis wormholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole) (and Ellis drainholes).
- The spaceships that carry the wormholes are traditional chemical rockets. However, they can go at great speeds because fuel and other resources can be delivered *through* the same wormhole it is tasked to carry. Also keep in mind that this means the wormholes will be time dilated significantly. In fact, that is a good thing, because it allows you to use the wormhole before its completed!
- An end of one wormhole can traverse through another wormhole.
- The only real restriction on how they are placed is that if they are arranged in such a way that they would form a [closed timelike curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve), they violently explode instead. However, it is also preferable for efficiency reasons to place them in orbits around things (because then the machine only needs to stabilize the wormhole, not levitate it).
- Wormhole Inc. has access to the galaxy's finest time-dilated quantum super computers and are willing to spend years on mission planning, so you have time to find a solution. Cheaper and faster is better.

EDIT: The question is how Wormhole Inc. can most efficiently distribute wormholes according to these rules, not how to change the rules to better accommodate Wormhole Inc. (although that is itself an interesting question).

Comment: If the chronology protection conjecture holds, then *it doesn't matter* how you arrange the wormholes. (Personally, I prefer the (weak) [cosmic censorship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis) hypothesis, which has the advantage of admitting a simple mathematical formulation.) Anyway, the point is that if either the chronology protection conjecture or any form of cosmic censorship hypothesis proves true, then this would prohibit time travel no matter how one tried to achieve it. It just would not work; the world would have no such thing as a closed time-like loop.

Comment: @AlexP time travel is impossible (in terms of closed time-like loops) no matter what, but this implies a restriction on the placement of wormholes. If you tried to place a wormhole on the moon with 2 or more seconds of time dilation, it would be destroyed by quantum fluctuations.

Comment: *"The moon example is fine, because even though you can go to the moon 1 second ago, it takes you at least 1.28 seconds to get back to Earth, so you can't actually change your own past using them"* Wormholes are necessarily two-way, so yes you can change your past in that example. If people are [moonbouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%E2%80%93Moon%E2%80%93Earth_communication) messages, someone can intercept those messages before they are received and thus apply changes to the timeline.

Comment: In the very least a wormhole far away gives you a window into the past, as you will receive light from it before light would arrive at you naturally. This is a violation of the light cone and there is no way around it other than plot and magic.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw if you use it to go from the moon back to the Earth, you go 1 second into the future. Future in one direction equals past in the other (relative to the same reference frame).

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw and going FTL is fine, as long as chronology is protected. General relativity is mathematically consistent with FTL and wormholes, so no magic is needed.

Comment: 'For example, if you want to appear on the moon 1 second ago, you can set up wormholes to do that.' Only if you set up the physics in your world to do this. 'Any form of FTL, including traversable wormholes, allows backwards time travel' Not an absolute assumption. Time intervals are not the same between observers in different frames of reference. What appears to be 'forward in time' to one observer could be 'fbackward in time' to another, but in any wormhole you can not arrive before you leave relative to the wormhole entrance frame of reference. Time still 'passes' in the wormhole.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I know that forward and backward in time is relative. But for any reference frame, you can set up a wormhole that would take you back in time according to that reference frame. On the other hand, whether a curve is a closed timelike curve is absolute.

Comment: It is absolute only in the reference frame of an observer at the origin of that 'curve'. It is not absolute for an observer in any other reference frame. For any reference frame, you can ONLY set up a wormole that goes forward in time from the reference frame of that origin. Every 'curve' is a brand new curve, relativte to that particular origin and reference frame. Any wormhole is NOT in the same 'curve' as a wirmhole from another reference point.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw  At the most, current science knows of no reason why a wormhole can't be two-way.  Given that they have not been observed, who knows what surprises they would yield once found?

Comment: @Mary I agree, but in this specific case the OP has stated that his wormholes are two-way.

Comment: Although there are mathematical descriptions of one way wormholes, they wouldn't be pleasant for traversing. The "in" end looks and acts like a black hole, since it has an event horizon.

Answer (score 4):

The classic [Traversable Wormhole FAQ](https://www.aleph.se/Trans/Tech/Space-Time/wormholes.html) goes into wormhole networks in some detail. Essentially, a wormhole network defines an "Empire time" of mutually spacelike-separated points which have, thanks to the wormholes, a shared simultaneity. Creating such a thing without violating the CPC would require some amount of planning; the FAQ suggests sending probes containing wormholes at high sublight speeds, using them as "seeds" through which you send more probes branching off in different directions to fill the entire space. Creating a plan for this sort of staggered penetration shouldn't be too hard for your quantum supercomputers.

The biggest problem I think you'd have is that, once you started off, pretty much everything would happen all at once. At high speeds, the amount of time dilation on the probe end of the wormhole would be significant, so you'd be able to go further and further in less and less time as the probes accelerate. Accelerating at 10g (and they could accelerate continuously, since you can pump fuel to them through the wormhole), in a year after launch your wormholes would be about 15 ly away; but only a year later, they'd be about 3000 light years away, and it'd only take 15 more months to get to the Andromeda galaxy. If you want to keep up a uniform probe density, you'll have to shoot more and more branch probes through more and more frequently as time goes on; either that, or throttle the acceleration based on the production rate for new wormholes.

Comment: So I guess the idea is that you keep track of this "empire time" and ensure that you don't place wormholes that allow light to go backwards in empire time?

Comment: Also, +1 for being the first person to understand the question.

Comment: I think that's the general idea, yes. The FAQ assumes that the CPC is enforced by the Visser effect, so wormholes just collapse when they get too close, rather than explode; presumably you'd want to be somewhat more careful. Could you use the Visser effect to detect when wormholes are too close to forming timelike curves, and close them manually, maybe?

Comment: perhaps, but the idea is to plan ahead. Either exploding or closing a wormhole is a huge waste of resources. (Although as a safety mechanism, manually destroying a wormhole might be a good idea.)

Comment: @PyRulez I was actually thinking about detecting the increased particle flux indicative of the Visser effect somehow, as a means of detecting "how close is this network to collapse?" But you're right, planning ahead is definitely the option you'd want to take.

Answer (score 3):

**The simplest solution** is to assume that the '*laws of physics*' including those pertaining to the creation of wormholes (WH) prevent anyone from using WH that violate the chronology protection conjecture (CPC). As as a result the CPC is no longer a conjecture but rather a fundamental principal of physics.

You can even 'write' into the background of your story that experiments conducted with (mirco) wormholes shortly after their first 'discovery' proved conclusively that any attempt to violate causality using one caused the WH concerned to 'collapse' the instant any attempt is made to send information through it.

It doesn't have to be a violent explosion either. The instant a particle or photon enters a micro-sized CPC violating WH it 'collapses' in on itself and/radiates out its (tiny) mass as sub-atomic particles.

So if you assume every 'large'/traversal WH starts off life as a 'seed' or micro hole that has to be actively expanded from a quantum scale anomaly up into something useful over time there won't be a violent explosion because you can't *grow* a CPC violating WH. You can either shield it from a CPC  event or 'grow it' but not both at once. This means the only WH you can 'grow' are ones that don't violate CPC.

PS: and no-one would try such an experiment even if they could with a macro sized WH because the dam things are hugely expensive to build - requiring an investment in exotic matter/negative mass/upsidasium/ *whatever* to expand upwards in scale. It would be like risking blowing up the LHC just to reproduce the same results you would get with $1000 worth of equipment in any run of the mill science lab.

Comment: Even if there is no explosion, it is much too expensive to waste wormholes like this.

Comment: Also, it's possible to move wormholes around, so it could be that a wormhole is fine when it is first created, but then you move the wormhole into an invalid position.

Comment: Another possibility is that you attempt to do it and you end up the place you intended but later than the last time you were there.

Comment: @Mary Recent conjecture about 'wormholes' at the event horizon of black holes posits that it takes as long to traverse a wormhole as it does to make the same journey through 'normal' space at the speed of light. One of the basic tenets of relativity is that time lapse looks different depending on the frame of reference. What could be a blink of an eye in one frame could be an eternity in another.

Comment: I'd suggest you that one end of the WH has to be shipped to its destination via a courier probe (taking decades or more) as a micro WH. Then once you've arrived you 'spin up' the WH in a predetermined orbit around its new star. By the time its big enough to send ships through its too large to move and therefore more or less 'fixed' in its original orbit like any other body orbiting that solar system. And thus too big/hard/expensive to move. Interestingly this means the WH network can only expand outwards at speeds considerably less than C but travel within it is FTL.

Answer (score 1):

The network topology you want is a tree. Earth is the trunk. Branches split off at Alpha Centauri. Each branch may split into as many branches as it likes, but they cannot connect to other branches.

What this means, practically, is that any world is allowed to send wormholes to any neighbouring solar systems that does not have any wormholes yet. But they are forbidden from sending wormholes to a system that is already connected to the network. Each system may have one uptime gate and as many downtime gates as they like.

For ease of navigation, you can let systems assign network addresses simply by counting their wormholes. Earth's address is 1. Alpha Centauri's address is 1.1. Alpha Centauri's connections: Beta Centauri is 1.1.1, Proxima Centauri is 1.1.2. And so on.

If you were at 1.1.2.6.2.5 and you wanted to get to 1.1.2.3.8.1 then you would immediately know that you have to go through the single uptime gate in each solar system until you get to 1.1.2 at Proxima Centauri, then follow the numbers downtime to 1.1.2.3, 1.1.2.3.8, 1.1.2.3.8.1.

This network will put Alpha Centauri at the centre of more galactic trade routes and communication lines than any other system. After a few centuries it may start to feel like Alpha Centauri is the capital city of the galaxy and Earth is the quiet suburb on the capital city's fringes.

Comment: So any ogrish despot controlling any node can completely cut off all systems downtime of him?

Comment: Well he can... but if he no longer has an uptime wormhole, then the galactic empire can safely send a new one to his system, with a whole fleet of warships falling out of it before his forces can take control of it... or leave him alone & let his worlds suffer from the self-inflicted trade embargo.

Comment: You're right that this does lend itself towards a sort of feudalism, where the owners of wormholes hierarchically have the ability to control or tax trade between larger and larger areas of the galaxy.

Comment: I don't think branching would be either necessary or sufficient to avoid exploding wormholes. If two branches which diverge early on in the system end up very close to one another, they could still create timelike curves.

Comment: @Robyn surely you would have back up wormholes, right?

Comment: If a back-up wormhole has a difference in the amount of time dilation that is greater than the time it takes for light to go through one wormhole & back through the other, then with the pair of wormholes and a few lasers you could send a message to your past self, which is forbidden. So I suppose you can have a back up wormhole, if the distance between them in light-minutes is always greater than any difference in their time dilations.

Comment: @gilgamec A branching network makes it easier. A tree has no loops, and allowing loops would require galaxy-wide analysis, which is a hassle in a trillion star galaxy, to stop wormhole builders accidentally creating a large unbalanced loop that would allow a determined traveller to go around the loop and shake hands with themself.

Comment: @Robyn My point is that "loops" are a function of how close two wormholes are in network-distance and how close in external spactime distance. Just having two trees of different network distance grow closer to each other would mean that we'd get loops even if they don't go to the same system, or even really close systems; for instance, if the difference in network time to the root is ten years, then any entrances within ten light years would be a "loop".

Comment: @Robyn the back up wormholes would presumably be set up to have the same time differences as the main ones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a problem. No need to blow anything up. See EDIT at the end for a more formal explanation.

Your assumption is that traversing a wormhole does not take as long as making the same trip by light speed. This is NOT a given. A wormhole between here and Alpha Centauri, for instance, could take 4.4 years to traverse, whether through a wormhole or the more scenic route traveling at the speed of light. Since wormholes are pure conjecture, time itself in a wormhole may not be (probably isn't) the same as time in normal space/time. I suppose it could be conjectured that, to the traveler, it may seem instantaneous. Wooops, in a blink of my eye, 4.4 years passed.

But if you WANT to use wormholes, so that you can travle FTL, such that you can only go into the future to protect the Chronology protection conjecture (a neat concept) then design the physics such that, when you travel through a wormhole in the direction you came from (the return loop of the circle), it takes twice as long as the trip would have at light speed. That is, you end up taking a very slow boat throught the wormhole to come back home, on the return leg. Leave the calculations for the time lapse up to your physics, not us poor humans. It's your world, since you are playing around with the laws of relativity anyway, you get to modify the rules in whatever fashion you want. Warp time in a way that suits your story, and make your wormholes into reverse time machines.

***EDIT***

To clarify the 'reverse time machine' concept.

If, for instance, I leave point **A** and go through a wormhole that actually takes less time to traverse than going the same distance the 'scenic' route to point **B** at **cee**, relative to the observer taking the scenic route at **cee**, it is true that I will arrive at the destination **B** before the light 'pulse' containing the information of my departure from **A** gets to **B**, so it might appear as if I arrived before I left. However, if I take the return trip (**B** to **A**), I will 'pass' that pulse of light in the opposite direction. I will NOT arrive back at the original destination **A** before the pulse of light is 'sent' from **A**, I will have passed that pulse of light in its journey. I will have 'caught up with time', and will still arrive back at my origin **A** after I first left.

If I turned around and looked 'back' to **B**, yes I would have arrived back at my original point **A** before the information containing my departure from **B** arrived at **A**, but again if I returned back to **B**, I would pass that pulse of light (information) and still arrive back at **B** AFTER I left **B**. In fact, I could pass the pulse of light going from **A** to **B** of my first departure, again, going in the same direction, and arrive at **B** beore both pulses of information arrive at **B** (first and second departure from **A**). But at no 'time' would I have an opportunity to change the data in either pulse of light. The 'ripples' of information from **A** would still be contiguous in time, as they arrived at **B**. The history would not have changed.

**TL:DR** That is, if you travel **AWAY** from the point that information is being transmited (originated) from at FTL, you are going one direction in 'time', ahead of the information travel. But if you travel back **TOWARDS** the origin of that information, you are traveling FORWARD in time again. You will always arrive at the origin **A** **after** the pulse of light was originally sent, relative to an observer at **A**.

Comment: The question isn't how the physics should work, it's how humans should arrange wormholes given the physics described. Wormholes would be the size and length of normal wormholes. A wormhole that that is 8 or 9 light-years long (on the *inside*) sounds insane.

Comment: On the other hand, there are many, many physicists who posit that, if wormholes actually do exist, they would take just as long to traverse as the speed of light through 'normal' space. They would not BE that long, they would just TAKE that long inside. Warping of space/time does NOT require space and time to be warped in the same proportion. You only GO a very short distance, but it takes a LONG time. A minor inconvenient possible 'truth' about wormholes. So indeed it IS about how the physics would work.

Comment: Your quote from the question seems to acknowledg that in some way you understand this. "Also keep in mind that this means the wormholes will be time dilated significantly." That one statement says it all. There is no such thing as 'instantaneously simultaneous same time at two points'. 'instantaneous simultaneity' of time depends on the speed of light. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/28-2-simultaneity-and-time-dilation/ for instance.

Comment: oh, you're taking about from earth's reference frame. I thought you meant in the ship's reference frame it would be 8 light-years.

Comment: I think in you answer you need to clarify which reference frame you are measuring the times in. As it stands, it is confusing whether the 4.4 years is according to the Earth's reference frame or the traveller's reference frame (or something else?).

Comment: Looked at another way, from an observer on the earth, where the wormhole origin was, a person going through the wormhole and a person traveling in a spaceship going at cee would both arrive at the destination at the same time. For an observer at the destination, both would arrive at the same time. And both travelers would have 'aged' exactly the same amount. Wormhole travel is so over-rated as a 'shortcut in time' in scifi, and requires a complete re-write of Einsteinian physics.

Comment: what speed is the traveller travelling? Because if there are traveling near c and it takes them 8 years, the length of the wormhole from their perspective was 8 light years.

Comment: That's the point - the traveler is going a t aparticular speed only with reference to another observer, perhaps in another frame of reference. Speed is not absolute. And it is only calculable with respect to one frame of reference. With the warping of space.time, the same distance from A to B as observed by one observer is not the same 'distance' as observed by abother. To an observer at D, the distance between A and B is exactly the same, whether it was through a wornhole or the scenic route. So the time to traverse it at c either in or out of it is the same.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I am talking about Ellis wormholes.

Answer (score 0):

It has been proven that, given that wormholes exist and they connect two regions of space instantly,  you can hurt the Chronology already with a single wormhole.

Check out this episode of Sean Carroll's Mindscape podcast where he explains a lot better than I could ever do:

https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/podcast/2020/11/23/124-solo-how-time-travel-could-and-should-work/

Here is a quote from the transcript. I really advise to take two hours during commute and listen to this podcast.

snip

Now, in fact, they later worked it down to just a single wormhole, and this is a little bit elaborate, but it’s worth explaining ’cause it’s just so cool. So, imagine one wormhole. Imagine we make a wormhole, don’t ask me how we make it, but we have these two spherical regions of space, the mouths of the wormhole, and you go in one, you instantly come out the other one, okay? And imagine that somehow, we can manipulate the mouths of the wormhole. We can basically put a tractor beam on and move one end of the wormhole around independently from the other one. So, this is the point, that there remains zero distance if you travel through the wormhole. You don’t actually traverse any distance going from one sphere to the other one, but from the point of view of someone outside, the two mouths of the wormhole could be very close, or they could be very far away. And so what Thorne and his friends say is, imagine that we move them, but we start them right next to each other so they’re very close, and we move one of them far away, and then we move it back. Okay?

1:22:25 SC: And they know the other one just stays constant, the other one stays put. This little thing that we just did, one mouth of the wormhole stays put, the other one moves out, let’s say close to the speed of light and then comes back, that should remind you of the twin paradox. If you put a clock on one wormhole and on the other one, the clock on the wormhole that stayed the same might know it reads an hour has passed. Well, let’s say this. Yeah, let’s say two hours have passed on the wormhole that stayed the same, on the mouth of the wormhole that stayed put, whereas the other one that went out and came back, its clock only reads one hour. Okay? So initially the two clocks, again, from the point of view of someone outside who’s watching all of these shenanigans, there’s two clocks, they both say noon, and then two hours passed from the point of view of the wormhole that stayed stationary, so its clock now says 2:00 PM, but the wormhole that went out and came back, its clock just as 1:00 PM. So they’re now out of sync by an hour.

1:23:28 SC: And you say, “Alright, that’s fine. Good special relativity, twin paradox. I get it.” But here’s the twist: When you look through the wormhole, you see what’s on the other side. You don’t see flashing lights, it’s not a subway, you see whatever is on the other side. It’s like a window, it’s like, you know, a telescope or something. You’re seeing through a view portal in space-time. And let’s imagine that our clocks are so arranged that you can see the clock on the other side, you can see the other wormhole’s clock, the other mouth of the wormhole’s clock, by looking through either sphere. So, when you’re moving, when the one wormhole is moving, it’s going out and coming back, what would I see if all along, I was looking through that wormhole at the stationary clock? Well, from the point of view of looking through the wormhole, nothing’s moving. There is still zero distance between the two mouths of the worm hole from the point of view of through the wormhole as opposed to outside. Outside the wormhole, the wormhole mouths are moving apart and then back together, but from looking through the wormhole, there’s always no change in distance whatsoever.

1:24:40 SC: And so you don’t see the other clock moving; you see it stationary. And therefore what you see is that clock ticking at one second per second, just like your clock. And that sounds paradoxical, because you say that, “Well, if I’m outside and I look at both clocks, one does a little twin paradox motion and goes forward one hour in time; one just days stationary and goes forward two hours, so now they’re out of sync,” but if, I instead of looking them from the outside, look through the wormhole, to borrow a phrase, they’re in sync. They both read the same time. So, once the wormhole that went out on a journey comes back, it says 1:00 PM, its friend that stayed behind says 2:00 PM, but when we look through the wormhole from the one that went out and came back to the other direction, we still see it saying 1:00 PM, ’cause it still has to say the same thing as the clock that was moving out and came back.

1:25:37 SC: And what that means is, I hope you followed this, I hope you bought everything I just said, what it means is if you go through the wormhole yourself from starting in the mouth that went out on its journey and came back and its clock says 1:00 PM, you come out the other wormhole not just in a different location in space, but also at a different moment in time compared to the point of view of the external observer. Since you are looking at the clock on the other side of the wormhole and it says 1:00 PM, you come out at 1:00 PM from the point of view of that wormhole mouth. So you have moved into the past from the point of view of the external observer. What the external observer sees is at 2:00 PM, you entered the wormhole, and at 1:00 PM, you exited. You exited before you left. And then you could hang around and there could be another copy of you that said hi to the copy of itself that went through the wormhole. An honest-to-goodness closed time-like curve that you made in a local region of space; you didn’t just put it into the universe from the start.

snip

Again, this is the link. Go there, take a look.

https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/podcast/2020/11/23/124-solo-how-time-travel-could-and-should-work/

Comment: There is no such thing in physics as 'instantly'.  From an observer somewhere, there will always be a time interval between any two events, no matter how simultaneous they 'appear' to be to another observer. 'C' is NOT the 'speed of light', it is the universal constant 'factor' that makes time and distance work in the Einsteinian world, the units of which are distance/time (which makes it APPEAR to be a 'speed', as we humans think of it, bit it is just a LINK between distance and time). However, it is not an absolutely necessary concept in the Quantum world of probablility and planck units.

Comment: Thanks for that remark Justin. The link I provided is a talk about time travel. I propose you listen to it before writing comments, because that "instantly" is exactly what makes a wormhole into a time machine.

Comment: My comment was about your statement 'they connect two regions of space instantly'. What is 'instantly' to one viewer may not be 'instatnly' to another. To one viewer, it may look like the traveler exited the wormhole before they entered. That is 'time travel' only from the perspective of 'information travel', not 'time travel'. Time travel and information travel are NOT the same thing. 'Infornation' does not always travel with the person. https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/College_Physics/Book%3A_College_Physics_(OpenStax)/28%3A_Special_Relativity/28.02%3A_Simultaneity_and_Time_Dilation

Comment: Quantum physics and probability, on the other hand, do not depend on 'information travel' or 'c', only on the probability of something happening at a particular moment in a particular place, irrespective of what happened anywhere else, from any other observer in any other frame of reference. Time travel in quantum physics is very different than time travel in Einsteinian physics, since pure quantum physics is not relativistic but probablistic. Nothing is continuous or even contiguous in quantum physics. Either this planck unit or that planck unit, in time and space.

Comment: Posted the explanation of Sean Carroll. Justin, now you just have to read it.

Comment: Again, it is that 'instantly' thing. Exactly how do you establish that someone has traversed the wornhole 'instantly'? That information woul dhave to travel between observers how - by speed of light? Or are you just assuming 'instantly'? Not in our world of established relativity physics. Simultaneity is impossible, Not even if the origin is the same as the destination. The ladder problem has pretty much settled the arguement. If 'simultaneity' can not be established, the arguement is moot.

Comment: Or do you want me to argue what the false logic and nebulous assumptions  in your posited mind experiment are? For starters, it is that 'moving the mouth at the speed of light' thing - what exactly is moving? You indeed have to dea with the space/time dilation of the object being moved. Then, there is that 'light travels through the wormhole' assumption. Does it really? If it did, then what would someone standing BEHIND the wornhole see? Nothngness?

Comment: And then, there is the notion that your 'mind experiment' allows you to take the clock in your hand, pass it through the looking glass into the other side, and then bring your hand back through with the clock, as if everything were contiguous between both ends of the wormhole. Is your arm in two places at the same time? What happens to your blood?  And does someone at the other end just see your arm? Wouldn't your arm be 'stretched' by time/space dilation? Like a black hole event horizon? All really big assumptions that have to be dealt with to me.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I am not sure why you think simultaneity is undefined in relativity. Although usually associated with Newtonian physics, simultaneity also has a relativistic version. See [Relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity). It is of course relative, like many other physical concepts in relativity.

Comment: I apologize if I left the impressiion that I was saying that simultaneity is not defined. It is clearly defined, and the math has been well developed. What I am saying is that in reletavistic physics, absolute simultaneity is impossible. There is a difference between 'not defined' and 'impossible'. In fact, methinks that before one can say something is impossible, it HAS to be defined, in order to be definitively proven to be impossible. But that is a philosophical discussion. The down vote was NOT mine.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond the answer didn't mention *absolute* simultaneity. Just simultaneity. I assume Andreas is talking about the relativistic version.

Comment: I do not know how this happened, but somehow a downvote was recorded by my avatar. I can not remove it until you edit the question. If you edit it, I will try to remove the downvote. This answer does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: I edited it. I didn't define any special version of simultanity. I just left a link to an interesting podcast by a physics professor who knows his stuff, who talked about exactly this topic here and is an interesting speaker.

Comment: Still can't undo my false down vote. No idea what is appening. My down vote appered after you put in the 'snip' edit, but I did not put it there. If you want, try another simple edit so I can remove my down vote. I can't remove it until the post is edited again.

Answer (score 0):

**Wormholes Pairs Take a Lot of Time to Set up**

Suppose you want to create a wormhole pair between here and Andromeda. The only way is to take two nearby regions of space (which are already entangled with each other by virtue of being next to each other ) and push them apart until one reaches Andromeda and the other reaches here.

The bridge takes 2.5 million years to build.

Of course after the bridge is built we can pop back and forth between galaxies very quickly. But the long setup period prevents information being transmitted faster than the speed of light. This protects the chronology.

Comment: Perhaps the question that needs to beanswered is 'How long does it take to traverse a wormhole?'.